# T-SQL select starting from value condition

Tags: t-sql, select, conditional-statements

In SQL server 2008, I have below table.

[image]

Thanks

```
create table test1 ([Number] int, Item varchar(10))
insert into test1 values (20 , 'Item 1'),(30 , 'Item 2'),(60 , 'Item 3'),(23 , 'Item 4'),(10 , 'Item 5'),(76 , 'Item 6'),(44 , 'Item 7'),(99 , 'Item 8'),(10 , 'Item 9'),(22 , 'Item 10'),(77 , 'Item 11'),(10 , 'Item 12')
```

Comment: How do you determine the "order" of your items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Without** a specific primary key, there is **no inherent** order to the data in the table, e.g. imagine each record as a sheet of paper dumped in a basket (in no particular order).

```
select a.*--, b.pvt
from test1 a
inner join (select MIN(1*substring(item,6,10)) pvt from test1 where number=10) b
    on 1*substring(a.item,6,10) >= b.pvt
order by 1*substring(a.item,6,10)
```

I have made the following assumptions:

- The order is by the Item number, where
- Item number is always the 6th character onwards in the column "Item"

If the assumptions are wrong, then you can still use a similar technique, which is to find the pivotal record and join to it using `>=`